# Regex that validate a string consist of 3-4 char followed by semicolon

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to make a regex that validate a string is in this format:

```
".xml;.mp4;.webm;.wmv;.ogg"
```

file format separated with semicolon.

what is the best way to do this?

Comment: The best way would be to actually write a Regex, and if you struggle post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try using the pattern `^(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]{3,4})(?:;\.[A-Za-z0-9]{3,4})*$`:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"^(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]{3,4})(?:;\.[A-Za-z0-9]{3,4})*$");
Match match = regex.Match(".xml;.mp4;.webm;.wmv;.ogg");
if (match.Success)
{
   Console.WriteLine("MATCH");
}
```

Explanation:

```
^                         from the start of the string
(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9]{3,4})    match a dot followed by 3-4 alphanumeric characters
(?:;\.[A-Za-z0-9]{3,4})*  then match semicolon, followed by dot and 3-4 alphanumeric
                          characters, that quantity zero or more times
$                         match the end of the string
```

Side note: I used `?:` inside the terms in parentheses, which in theory should tell the regex engine *not* to capture these terms.  This might improve performance, though perhaps at the cost of the pattern being slightly less readable.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, but need to check for only one format (if list has only one format, will it be followed by semicolon).

```
^(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+;)*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```